# Magento 1.6 add tab to customer edit on back end

Tags: php, magento, backend, magento-1.6

I've been trying to add a tab to the Customer Information page in Magento CE 1.6.

I've tried the following examples:

- [how to add custom tabs to magento customer edit page](http://www.mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/) on mydons.com
- [how to add tab in customer information in magento admin](http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/) on nextbits.eu
- [how to add tab in customer information](http://ankursphp.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information.html) on ankursphp.blogspot.com

The last one is the only one that even seems to come close.  However, it has two problems.  One is it edits core files and two is that when I click on the tab it spins and dyes.  Chrome DevTools show the server reporting 404.

Can anyone provide me with some decent documentation or code that is compatible with Magento 1.6?

---

**Edit** Adding the text from the last link as that seems to be the only one that remotely worked.

1. Override the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php`,Inside `_beforeToHtml()` method, add the following code:

   ```
   $this->addTab('Custom',array(
   'label' =>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Custom'),
   'class' =>   'ajax',
   'url'   =>   $this->getUrl('*/*/custom',array('_current'=>true)),
   ));
   ```
2. Override the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php`, Add the following code:

   ```
   public function customAction()
   { $this->_initCustomer();
   $this->getResponse()->setBody(
   Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/customer/tab/custom.phtml')->setCustomerId(Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
       ->setUseAjax(true)->toHtml()   
   ); 

   }
   ```
3. Create the file `/app/code/core/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/` and create `Custom.php`, Add the following source code to the file:

   ```
   <?php
   class Custom_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
   {
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->setTemplate('custom/customer/tab/custom.phtml');
   }
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Now, you need to create a template file. Go to `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/customer/tab/` and create `custom.phtml`,

Comment: Can you add more information about what you tried? If the links goes down, nobody can access it.

Comment: Added the information form the third link -  adding the other two would render all three unreadable IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to track down some out of the box code that works without any modification as a starting point:

http://www.engine23.com/magento-how-to-create-custom-customer-tab-and-submit-a-form.html

app/etc/modules/Russellalbin_Customertab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Russellalbin_Customertab>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Russellalbin_Customertab>
</modules>
</config>
```

app/etc/local/Russellalbin/Customertab/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Russellalbin_Customertab>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Russellalbin_Customertab>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customertab>
                    <file>customertab.xml</file>
                </customertab>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <russellalbin_customertab before="Mage_Adminhtml">Russellalbin_Customertab_Adminhtml</russellalbin_customertab>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customertab>
                <class>Russellalbin_Customertab_Block</class>
            </customertab>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Russellalbin/Customertab/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Action.php

```
/**
 * Adminhtml customer action tab
 *
 */
class Russellalbin_Customertab_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Action
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('customertab/action.phtml');
    }

    public function getCustomtabInfo()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        $customtab = 'Mail Order Comics Pull List';
        return $customtab;
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Customer Pull List');
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Pull List Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        return (bool)$customer->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Defines after which tab, this tab should be rendered
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAfter()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Russellalbin/Customertab/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomertabController.php

```
class Russellalbin_Customertab_Adminhtml_CustomertabController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    function resetAction()
    {
        $params = array();
        $path = 'customer';
        $customer_id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id');

        if($customer_id)
        {
            // Do your stuff here


            $params['id'] = $customer_id;
            $params['back'] = 'edit';
            $params['tab'] = 'customer_edit_tab_action';
            $path = 'adminhtml/customer/edit/';
        }

        $params['_store'] = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(0);

        $url = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl($path, $params);
        Mage::app()
            ->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url);

        Mage::app()
            ->getResponse()
            ->sendResponse();

        exit;
    }

}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customertab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>customer_edit_tab_action</name>
            <block>customertab/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_action</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customertab/action.phtml

```
<div id="customer_info_tabs_customer_edit_tab_action_content">
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">Pull List</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="group_fields4" class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
            <div class="hor-scroll">
                <h2>This is my form and content that I can submit and return back to this page and tab</h2>
                <div><form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/customertab/reset/', array('customer_id'=> $customer_id)); ?>" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Post This Form" /></form></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mmm, it seems a really interesting approach to the problem: php - xml - and phtml file as the markup.. all good but I think it's A+ better practice to echo your outputs UN-encoded and perhaps do the char-set to "utf-8" at the head previous to the body as shown above. I believe that is so for readability because of progressive enhancement perspective... is so as:~ <?=$this->getUrl(' ... ~code~  ; ?> ~This approach is good for portability of code & readability. Magent is an E-commerce repository & an software platform.. so new versions will happen to arise & the easier to port it is a plus~  :)

Answer (score 0):

1. **app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml**: make sure you declare your block alias and your adminhtml layout file:

   ```
   <config>
       ...
       <global>
           ...
           <blocks>
               <namespace_module>
                   <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
               </namespace_module>
           </blocks>
           ...
       </global>
       ...
       <adminhtml>
           ...
           <layout>
               <updates>
                   <namespace_module>
                       <file>namespace/module.xml</file>
                   </namespace_module>
               </updates>
           </layout>
           ...
       </adminhtml>
       ...
   </config>
   ```
2. **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/namespace/module.xml**: declare your new tab

   ```
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       ...
       <adminhtml_customer_edit>
           <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
               <action method="addTabAfter">
                   <name>custom_tab</name><!--can be anything you want-->
                   <block>namespace_module/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom</block>
                   <after>account</after><!-- after which tab do you want it -->
               </action>
           </reference>
       </adminhtml_customer_edit>
       ...
   </layout>
   ```
3. **app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Custom.php**: this is your block class

   ```
   <?php

   class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Custom
       extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
       implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
   {

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->setTemplate('namespace/module.phtml');
       }

       public function getTabLabel()
       {
           return Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Tab Label');
       }

       public function getTabTitle()
       {
           return Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Tab Title');
       }

       public function canShowTab()
       {
           return true;
       }

       public function isHidden()
       {
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```
4. **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/namespace/module.phtml**: content of the tab:

   ```
   enter html code here
   ```

Comment: thanks for the attempt to help.  Is this the bare minimum code to get a tab to display? I've tried it verbatim (With the ellipses removed from the xml files) and I'm not getting anything on the customer information page, no tab, no errors.

Comment: @Wranorn this is going inside your module, the only thing missing is the module's declaration file (`app/etc/modules/Namespace/Module.xml`) but I assume you already have that. This is not supposed to be used *verbatim*, this is not how SO works: for instance, I am pretty sure your namespace isn't *Namespace* and your module isn't called *Module*. This is the code you need, but you have to understand it and modify it to match your specs.